# Buildingerror of Xamarin project in Microsofts Appcenter

Tags: ios, xamarin, build

I have a xamarin project where I added the iOS part later and add all necceserry references.
I build the android solution in the microsoft appcenter and everything works fine, but building the iOS version freaking me out. I'm getting the following errors, someone run into the same problem?

```
"/Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/PLUTester.sln" (Rebuild target) (1) ->
"/Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/PLUTester/PLUTester.iOS/PLUTester.iOS.csproj" (Rebuild target) (4) ->
(_XamariniOSBuildResourceRestore target) -> 
  /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/packages/Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.11/build/Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(74,3): error : Sharing violation on path /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/packages/Xamarin.Google.iOS.SignIn.5.0.1.1/lib/xamarinios10/Google.SignIn.dll [/Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/PLUTester/PLUTester.iOS/PLUTester.iOS.csproj]
/Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/packages/Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.11/build/Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(74,3): error :   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0019e] in <ba70b91736bd40cb990a357097dba9c3>:0  [/Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/PLUTester/PLUTester.iOS/PLUTester.iOS.csproj]
/Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/packages/Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.11/build/Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(74,3): error :   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <ba70b91736bd40cb990a357097dba9c3>:0  [/Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/PLUTester/PLUTester.iOS/PLUTester.iOS.csproj]
/Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/packages/Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.11/build/Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(74,3): error :   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare) [/Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/PLUTester/PLUTester.iOS/PLUTester.iOS.csproj]
/Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/packages/Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.11/build/Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(74,3): error :   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.GetFileStream (System.String fileName, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00006] in <be358b898f7b4f70a597f036aed20add>:0  [/Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/PLUTester/PLUTester.iOS/PLUTester.iOS.csproj]
/Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/packages/Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.11/build/Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(74,3): error :   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Write (System.String fileName, Mono.Cecil.WriterParameters parameters) [0x00006] in <be358b898f7b4f70a597f036aed20add>:0  [/Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/PLUTester/PLUTester.iOS/PLUTester.iOS.csproj]
/Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/packages/Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.11/build/Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(74,3): error :   at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.Write (System.String fileName, Mono.Cecil.WriterParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <be358b898f7b4f70a597f036aed20add>:0  [/Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/PLUTester/PLUTester.iOS/PLUTester.iOS.csproj]
/Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/packages/Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.11/build/Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(74,3): error :   at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.Write (System.String fileName) [0x00007] in <be358b898f7b4f70a597f036aed20add>:0  [/Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/PLUTester/PLUTester.iOS/PLUTester.iOS.csproj]
/Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/packages/Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.11/build/Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(74,3): error :   at Xamarin.Build.Download.BaseXamarinBuildResourceRestore.MergeResources (Mono.Cecil.IAssemblyResolver resolver, System.String originalAsmPath, System.String mergedAsmPath, System.String assemblyName, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] resourceItems) [0x000fc] in <f9293fcab5a14114beee6a1e59102a2c>:0  [/Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/PLUTester/PLUTester.iOS/PLUTester.iOS.csproj]
```

Comment: Try bump the Xamarin.Build.Download package to the latest version.

Comment: Thank yo for the tip, but that changed nothing.